# Convert a Date from mm/dd/yyyy to dd MMM yyyy

Tags: c#, .net

How Do I convert a datetime from mm/dd/yyyy to dd MMM yyyy?  DateTime.ParseExact or DateTime.TryParseExact does not require a parameter that tells it what format I want it in.  So how does it know that I want it to return the passed in date to dd MMM yyyy format?

```
DateTime result;
var dateTime = DateTime.TryParseExact("03/21/2013", "mm/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
```

Comment: Your `dateTime` variable there is a boolean - the `TryParseExact` method returns a boolean indicating whether or not the parsing was successful. Assuming it's successful, the value will be stored in your `result` variable.

Comment: Oh, and lower case 'm' is for minute, not month, so your parse statement needs to have `"MM/dd/yyyy`", or more correctly `"MM\\/dd\\/yyyy"` (the backslash escapes out the forward slash so the system knows that it's a true forward-slash and not a special character represented by a forward-slash - it's complicated, but definitely use the backslash). (Oh, and the two backslashes are because it's a C# escape character, so it's really only one).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `DateTime` object you get back has no formatting - it's just the raw date and time. To convert it to your new format after you've got it in a `DateTime` object, you call `ToString` on it, like:

```
string formattedDate = result.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTime` object does not store the date in string format. Rather you *may* output the value of `DateTime` using the format you like when obtaining a string representation:

```
// assuming you have date DateTime object variable named dateTime
dateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyyy");
```